convert video to audio using ffmpeg
I'm trying to convert a video to mp3 using ffmpeg library but ffmpeg command is not working, it is returning the code 1
Video conversion to MP3 failed with return code: 1
try {
  final session = await FFmpegKit.execute('-i $videoFilePath -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 192k -f mp3 $audioFilePath');

  final returnCode = await session.getReturnCode();

  if (ReturnCode.isSuccess(returnCode)) {
    print('Video conversion to MP3 successful!');
  } else {
    print('Video conversion to MP3 failed with return code: $returnCode');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print('Error occurred during video conversion: $e');
}

$videoFilePath - /Users/shaktigoyal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9D514AC1-E245-4360-B876-745B9527B844/data/Containers/Data/Application/091D48E6-3AE4-4867-B3B2-2034854D27CE/tmp/image_picker_3DA6CDD3-C2F9-4313-98A1-40A7B0AED652-1298-00001B041C9F94E4trim.59BC5143-1EBA-4BB0-955C-EA1942FA56E3.MOV
$audioFilePath - /Users/shaktigoyal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/9D514AC1-E245-4360-B876-745B9527B844/data/Containers/Data/Application/091D48E6-3AE4-4867-B3B2-2034854D27CE/Documents/audio-14.mp3

At the Terminal, I tested your command as follows: ffmpeg -i /Users/dave/Downloads/vid.mov -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 192k -f mp3 /Users/dave/Downloads/vid.mp3
It worked as expected, so I would check the file path for both $videoFilePath and $audioFilePath

so the $videoFilePath comes from ImagePicker which points to the temporary directory path and where as $audioFilePath points to application document directory where I'm saving it as a audio file @DavidM.Helmuth

Got it, I would try including the full file path for the video you want to read and full file path for audio file you want to create. Remember that in Windows system, that would be something "C:/temp/mymove.mov"

it has full path for both video as well as audio! I confirmed it by printing in the terminal @DavidM.Helmuth

updated the question! I have mentioned the path of both video and audio @DavidM.Helmuth

My last idea: Install FFMpeg. If you are using a Mac, you will need to install Homebrew first. (Homebrew is used to install FFMpeg on MacOS) Once installed, try to do your conversion from the terminal. Also, make sure to try with another video file, just in case there is an issue with the file you are using. Last, try using other directories just in case you have a permissions issue.
Good luck, because those are my last ideas.

so just installed FFMpeg on mac and tested the command on terminal and it worked! Now this makes me wonder why same command isn't working in flutter app (it has permissions to write the files to application document directory) @DavidM.Helmuth

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Add -report to the command and rerun. Share report file.
